# ocultar items que no cumplen una condicion jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo en jquery

```
$('#prueba').click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     $('[data-coc != "2"]').hide();
})
```

mi problema es que esta ocultando toda la pagina, cuando deberia ocultar los items que no poseen el data-coc = 2

Comment: ¿Qué es `data-coc`, una clase, un id...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás tratando de operar con los selectores de **JQuery** de una manera inapropiada. Para lograr lo que pretendes conseguir podrías usar la función `not()`, que te permite restringir elementos dentro de un grupo.

Lo que hace la función es seleccionar todos los `<div>` que no tengan atributo personalizado `data-coc` con valor a 2 y los oculta.

```js
$('#prueba').click(function(){
     $('div').not('[data-coc="2"]').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-coc="2">
  <p>NO se oculta 1</p>
</div>
<div data-coc="2">
  <p>NO se oculta 2</p>
</div>
<div data-coc="1">
  <p>Se oculta 1</p>
</div>
<div data-coc="1">
  <p>Se oculta 2</p>
</div>
<div data-coc="2">
  <p>NO se oculta 3</p>
</div>

<button type="button" id="prueba">Ocultar</button>
```